# Is it possible to run matlab function with several command line arguments?

Tags: bash, matlab, scripting, command-line-arguments

I want to write a script that runs several tests in matlab.
First I run:

```
TestsPath=$(find . -path "Tests")
```

Which returns:

```
a/b/Tests/ b/c/Tests/ c/d/Tests/
```

Then I try to launch matlab and pass these in (and for now only print them)

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run(RunAllTests(${TestsPath}));"
```

And my matlab function looks like:

```
function [] = RunAllTests(varargin)
    for i=1:nargin
        disp(varargin{i});
    end
end
```

But this

```
  run(a/b/Tests
  |

Error: This statement is incomplete.
```

So it seems that it breaks when it comes to the first white space.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you cannot pass the paths one by one, why not loop over them in bash? Just write a wrapper around the call to MATLAB, which loops over all test directories found.

Comment: But then I need to re-open matlab for each of the test cases. Since I can not (in the bash script) launch matlab and then continuously pass things to it. Right?

Comment: Or, if the answer works, write a bash wrapper to insert apostrophes and commas into your `TestPath` string and pass that. Since it breaks on spaces, I presume you cannot do this in MATLAB? Thus pass the string with spaces to the function, then do a `strplit` and work with the separated arguments

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need commas between the function arguments, enclose them in single quotes so matlab sees them as strings, and run is not necessary.

```
TestsPath="'a/b/Tests/', 'b/c/Tests/', 'c/d/Tests/'"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "RunAllTests(${TestsPath})"
```

If you don’t want to add commas between arguments, you could pass TestsPath as a single string an split it up into multiple arguments in matlab.

```
TestsPath="'a/b/Tests/ b/c/Tests/ c/d/Tests/'"
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "RunAllTests(strsplit(${TestsPath}))"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any spaces in your paths, the following should work:

```
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "RunAllTests ${TestsPath}"
```

Using your example, it is the same as running the following in Matlab:

```
RunAllTests a/b/Tests/ b/c/Tests/ c/d/Tests/
```

which results in `varargin = {'a/b/Tests/', 'b/c/Tests/', 'c/d/Tests/'}` within your function. Each argument passed to your function in this manner is treated as a character array.

Comment: This is how I was running it in the beginning. And does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that file names are enclosed in quotes using the `-printf` action for `find`:

```sh
TestsPath=$(find . -path "Tests" -printf "'%p' ")
```

This will return

```
'a/b/Tests/' 'b/c/Tests/' 'c/d/Tests/'
```

which is OK to substitute into a MATLAB [command syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) function call as suggested by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756796/7328782):

```sh
matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r "RunAllTests ${TestsPath};"
```

Note that these quotes are needed if there are spaces in the directory names.

---

Note that since MATLAB R2019b, `-r` is deprecated in favor of the new `-batch` command-line option:

```sh
matlab -batch "RunAllTests ${TestsPath};"
```

This works identically on all platforms (including Windows!).

Comment: Adds `"'%p',"` an additional `,` at the end of the string. Is this still fine?

Comment: @FelixRosén: You are right! I have edited the answer to remove the commas altogether, and using Alex's suggestion of using the command syntax instead of function syntax.